# Deploying WAR in TomEE

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, server, war

I have my WAR inside webapps of TomEE.
After delpoying, when I try to run the application, it says it is not able to see the classes that are present under **Project/WEB-INF/classes**.

I also tried packaging those classes into a separate jar and loaded that jar under **WEB-INF/lib**.

I am not sure why it is not able to see the classes that are undeployed under WEB-INF/classes.

Could someone please help me with this ?

EDIT 1 :

Error log :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.app.auth.AuthenticationService
    com.app.auth.AuthenticationInit.doInit(AuthenticationInit.java:14)
    org.zkoss.zk.ui.metainfo.InitiatorInfo.doInit(InitiatorInfo.java:148)
    org.zkoss.zk.ui.metainfo.InitiatorInfo.newInitiator(InitiatorInfo.java:143)
    org.zkoss.zk.ui.metainfo.PageDefinition.doInit(PageDefinition.java:396)
    org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.Initiators.doInit(Initiators.java:58)
    org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execNewPage0(UiEngineImpl.java:378)
    org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execNewPage(UiEngineImpl.java:312)
    org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.DHtmlLayoutServlet.process(DHtmlLayoutServlet.java:215)
    org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.DHtmlLayoutServlet.doGet(DHtmlLayoutServlet.java:136)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

EDIT 2: How I created the WAR file :

I created the WAR file from **eclipse** by right clicking the project and selecting **Export** as WAR file.

[image: In the attached image, I deselected Target runtime]

Comment: Hi! Please, add the error log so we can see better whatś happening

Comment: @Alfabravo Added them

Comment: Can you add steps you take to create the WAR file?

Comment: @Boris I created the WAR from eclipse. You can find this information in my EDIT 2.

Comment: And what are the contents of the WAR file? Is it an open source project by any chance so that you could share a link to a git repo?

Comment: @Boris It is a dynamic web project which I am exporting as WAR file. So it contains java resources, web content etc. Is there anything else that you want to know specifically ?

Comment: @Boris it is not an open source project and sorry I cant share it.

Comment: Is it a maven project? Then you could try to create the WAR in an alternative way, for example [$ mvn package](https://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-build-project-with-maven/)

Comment: @Boris No it is not a maven project